# Minted causing emergency stop under windows 11

Tags: minted, windows

Using minted package caused my beamer emergency stop.
I have installed pygments and added -shell-escape.

[image]

After I deleted "\usepackage{minted}",there is no error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Provide some code reproduce your problems, we need more information in order to help you

Comment: Are you editing the Chinese with Minted? Also, please be clearer and post some code that others can help with.